# How many Coulomb branches do we (conjecturally) know?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, calabi-yau, symplectic-resolutions

*Physics preamble:* Attached to any $3$ or $4$ dimensional SCFT it is expected to be a Poisson variety $\mathcal{M}_C$ called the *Coulomb branch*. It should admit a symplectic resolution.

Moreover, attached to any Calabi-Yau threefold $X$ (maybe with extra conditions) is expected to be a $3d$ (and $4d$, but let's ignore that) SCFT. So we expect a <s>symplectic</s> resolution $\mathcal{M}_C(X)$ for any such $X$.

*Maths question:* Which such $\mathcal{M}_C(X)$ have been constructed by mathematicians so far?

---

n.b. I think if you take $X=(\text{ADE surface})\times(\text{elliptic curve})$, you get a quiver gauge theory SCFT, so are meant to get by [Braverman-Finkelberg-Nakajima](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03625.pdf) a slice in the affine Grassmannian $\text{Gr}_G$ where $G$ is the ADE group attached to the quiver.

Comment: Just one remark: the Coulomb branch is not expected to have a symplectic resolution. For example, the slices you mentioned do not have such a resolution unless you are in type A.

Answer (score 2):

**To motivate other people to give other answers**, I will sketch the example coming from *class S* 4d theories $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma,G)$ attached to a marked compact Riemann surface $\Sigma$  and a semisimple Lie group $G$, which in the ADE case is meant to correspond to $X=(\text{ADE surface})\times \Sigma$. In the following we write what is meant to be the *Higgs* branches of the 3d compactification "$\int_{S^1}\mathcal{T}(\Sigma,G)$", which is the Coulomb branches of their 3d dual theories.

So here are some examples of Coulomb branches
$$\Sigma\ =\ (\mathbf{P}^1,z_1)\hspace{10mm} \rightsquigarrow\hspace{10mm} \mathcal{M}_C\ =\ G\times \mathcal{S}_e$$
$$\Sigma\ =\ (\mathbf{P}^1,z_1,z_2)\hspace{10mm} \rightsquigarrow\hspace{10mm} \mathcal{M}_C\ =\ T^*G$$
where $\mathcal{S}_e$ is the Slodowy slice to a regular nilpotent element.  Then by induction, given the space $\mathcal{M}_{C,n}$ when we have $\mathbf{P}^1$ with $n$ marked points, he defines by induction
$$\mathcal{M}_{C,n+m-2}\ =\ (\mathcal{M}_{C,n}\times\mathcal{M}_{C,m})//G$$
which by induction carries a symplectic action of $G$. See e.g. Arakawa's ["Chiral algebras of class S and Moore-Tachikawa symplectic varieties"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.01577.pdf) for a review.

For a general compact marked Riemann surface $(\Sigma,z_1,...,z_n)$
[image]

take a limiting nodal curve with irreducible components $\mathbf{P}^1$'s, and define $\mathcal{M}_C$ to be the symplectic reduction of $\mathcal{M}_{C,\mathbf{P}^1,n_1}\times\cdots \times \mathcal{M}_{C,\mathbf{P}^1,n_k}$ with respect to one copy of $G$ acting on a pair of multiplicands for each node.